# Setting up Salesforce

Tags: managed-package

I was going through the steps mentioned http://ccoenraets.github.io/salesforce-lightning-tutorial/setup-environment.html

1) Login to your Salesforce Developer Edition

2) Click Setup (upper right corner)

3) Click Create > Packages (left navigation)

4) Click Edit and Continue

However, I couldn't find above options. On clicking Setup I could find only "Installed Packages".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was way old, at least 3 years old, mid-2015. Now Lightning Components are not in beta, they are Generally Available.

You can directly start building lightning components in Dev console(Given that you have My Domain enabled)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please point me to some articles (beginner level) which can help me develop/test/deploy basic app.

Comment: @ravi this is best source out there I have seen, and SF team makes sure, that the data is always up to date.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics